# Byobu doesn't seem to launch

Tags: byobu

I recently bought a VPS which is running on Ubuntu 14.04. I connected to it fine via SSH and have installed byobu using apt-get. I have used the byobu-enable command, but after closing the session and re-entering, the byobu interface doesn't appear - my SSH client window does have byobu in the title, but the interface for it is not present, nor are any of the keyboard commands working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is a problem with your VPS.  Who is your provider?  What is the underlying technology?

I bet Byobu doesn't have write access to `/dev/shm`.  Try setting the environment variable to somewhere you can write, like this:

```
$ export BYOBU_RUN_DIR=$HOME/.byobu/run/
$ byobu
```

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Success! Works as intended. I really appreciate you taking the time to help me out. Thanks a bunch!